# Where is the registry key that point to location of $NTUninstall folders?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2003-r2

I am running out of room on the C: drive on my Windows Server 2003 R2 Server and want to move the $NTUninstall files to D:\Uninstall_Folder and update the registry key that tells Windows where to look for them. I have seen this done in the past but can't seem to find that registry key.

Answer (score 1):

Most updates you install will have a subkey created under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates`. That subkey will include an `UninstallString"`value that refers to the uninstall for the patch. Some updates, however, will be listed under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` with other non-update software, and will have an `UninstallString` value there.